# How do I resample SimpleITK images to same direction (i.e. view)?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, itk, simpleitk, medical-imaging

I would like to know how can I resample, for example 3D MRI Brain scans, from Coronal to Axial image view, without changing target image dimensions.

Image 1 information:

- View: Coronal
- Dimension: `(256, 256, 128)`

Image 2 information:

- View: Axial
- Dimension `(512, 512, 200)`

**I would like to resample Image 1 to Axial view and keep its size (i.e `256x256x128`), meaning, I do not want to use methods such as SimpleITK's resample method in order to resample target to reference image. Reason is because I have large dataset for which I wish to change image view ONLY.**

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to change your view from coronal to axial without changing the volume dimensions you have to resample, since the z axis in the coronal view changes from length 128 to 256 when it becomes the new y axis in the axial view and the same is true form the y axis in the coronal view as it changes to the new z axis. if you won't resample the dimention of your volume will become (128, 256, 256) and you can achive that by casting your itk object to an array and transposing your volume.

Comment: @yannziselman here is what I've tried so far based on your comment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840072/transpose-3-d-mri-image-axis-to-different-image-view. Btw, can you post an answer here so I can accept it?

Comment: no thank you, if my comment solved your problem, you are welcomed to post it as a self answer and accept